# Using Roslyn to determine if a BinaryExpression is an arithmetic expression

Tags: c#, roslyn, expression-trees, code-analysis

Using a CSharpSyntaxRewriter I'd like to determine if a a particular BinaryExpression is an Artihmetic expression. Is there a simpler way to determine this than to code snippet below.

```
private static bool IsArithmeticOperator(BinaryExpressionSyntax node)
{
    return node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.AddExpression) ||
        node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.MultiplyExpression) ||
        node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.DivideExpression) ||
        node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SubtractExpression) ||
        node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ModuloExpression);
}
```

Just feels a little clunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this is possible, but there is something in the enum that maybe can help you,
the arithmetic expression are in order inside the enum `SyntaxKind` except `ModuloExpression` which you can check separately.

maybe other `SyntaxKind` in this range will also be good for your needs.

```
AddExpression = 307,
SubtractExpression = 308,
MultiplyExpression = 309,
DivideExpression = 310,
IntegerDivideExpression = 311,
ExponentiateExpression = 314,
LeftShiftExpression = 315,
RightShiftExpression = 316,
ConcatenateExpression = 317,
ModuloExpression = 318,
```

So you can do something like this :

```
private static bool IsArithmeticOperator(BinaryExpressionSyntax node)
{
    SyntaxKind expressionKind = node.Kind();
    return (expressionKind >= SyntaxKind.AddExpression && expressionKind <= SyntaxKind.DivideExpression)
    || expressionKind == SyntaxKind.ModuloExpression;
}
```

**Update**

This will work only for `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic`

and wont work for `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`

Comment: Like the idea +1. Bit nervous about depending on the specific values, though. Worth nothing that on 3.7. of Microsoft.CodeAnalysiss.CSharp the values are a little different, and may have broken any implementation that depended on the values being as above. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @JamesWiseman are your sure ? this was took from Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic SyntaxKind

Comment: Mine was C# admittedly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxkind?view=roslyn-dotnet